# How to instantiate a javascript class in another js file?

Tags: javascript

Suppose if I define a class in file1.js

```
function Customer(){
    this.name="Jhon";
    this.getName=function(){
        return this.name;
    };
};
```

Now if I want to create a Customer object in file2.js

```
var customer=new Customer();
var name=customer.getName();
```

I am getting exception: `Customer is undefined, not a constructor.`

But when i create a customer object in file2.js and pass it to file1.js then its working .

```
file1.js

    function Customer(){
        this.name="Jhon";
        this.getName=function(){
            return this.name;
        }
    }
    function customer(){
        return new Customer();
    }

file2.js

    var customer=customer();
    var name=customer.getName();
```

but i want to create a customer object in file1.js using new Customer(). How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 46):

It depends on what environment you're running in. In a web browser you simply need to make sure that `file1.js` is loaded before `file2.js`:

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

In node.js, the recommended way is to make file1 a [module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) then you can load it with the `require` function:

```
require('path/to/file1.js');
```

It's also possible to use node's module style in HTML using the [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) library.

Comment: Thank you!  I needed to break up my React file into multiple classes and I couldn't use the require because it's not supported in the web browser.  I can just simple reference class component A from class component B without any require, import or export.  I simply needed to load FileA before File B.

Comment: @Thuy React jsx compiler automatically splits your project into multiple small js files. Are you not using jsx?

Comment: I can't install nodejs in my project web resources, so I need to link all of the React files necessary in the HTML file.  That way, I don't need the require when one React file refers to another file.

Comment: You only need node.js on your development PC/Mac/Laptop. You don't need it on your server. React compiles everything to static html and js files that you can then serve on anything

Comment: You need node.js to write react code. You don't need node.js to run react code. Think of node.js as the compiler for React projects.

Answer (score 27):

```
// Create Customer class as follows:
export default class Customer {
   getName() {
     return 'stackoverflow';
   }
}

// Import the class 
// no need for .js extension in path cos it gets inferred automatically
import Customer from './path/to/Customer'; 
// OR
const Customer = require('./path/to/Customer') 

// Use the class
var customer = new Customer();
var name = customer.getName();
```

Comment: Although this solution works like a charm, this needs babel setup in the nodejs config. Learn't it the hard way!

Comment: @Krishna -- this could be my issue. When the class is defined in a separate file, instances passed between the files are not recognizing the class instances and allowing the methods. Do you have a link to the babel setup solution?

Comment: @user172431 `npm install babel-cli babel-core --save-dev`.  Search [https://www.npmjs.com]

Comment: I'm getting two errors. One, `SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module` 
Two, `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: @AaronFranke, ```require``` above is for ```Node.js``` applications, but there is a ```require.js``` library file that you can add to your project [npmjs.com/package/require.js] or [npmjs.com/package/require.js].

Answer (score 9):

You can export your methods to access from other files like this:

file1.js

```
var name = "Jhon";
exports.getName = function() {
  return name;
}
```

file2.js

```
var instance = require('./file1.js');
var name = instance.getName();
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using javascript in HTML, you should include `file1.js` and `file2.js` inside your html:

```
<script src="path_to/file1.js"></script>
<script src="path_to/file2.js"></script>
```

Note, `file1` should come first before `file2`.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the dom is loaded before you run your code in file2... If you're using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  var customer=customer();
  var name=customer.getName();
});
```

Then it doesn't matter what order the files are in, the code won't run until all of the files are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Possible Suggestions to make it work:

Some modifications (U forgot to include a semicolon in the statement `this.getName=function(){...}` it should be `this.getName=function(){...};`)

```
function Customer(){
this.name="Jhon";
this.getName=function(){
return this.name;
};
}
```

(This might be one of the problem.)

and

Make sure U Link the JS files in the correct order

```
<script src="file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is saying the value is `undefined` because it is a constructor `function`, not a `class` with a `constructor`. In order to use it, you would need to use `Customer()` or `customer()`.

First, you need to load file1.js *before* file2.js, like slebetman said:

```
<script defer src="file1.js" type="module"></script>
<script defer src="file2.js" type="module"></script>
```

Then, you could change your file1.js as follows:

```
export default class Customer(){
    constructor(){
        this.name="Jhon";
        this.getName=function(){
            return this.name;
        };
    }
}
```

And the file2.js as follows:

```
import { Customer } from "./file1";
var customer=new Customer();
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.